# What type of function is main()?

Tags: functional-programming, c++

As the functions are of 2 type:
1.Pre-defined/library functions,
2.User defined functions.

What type of function is *main()* function?

This doubt comes in my mind while writing a program we define the *main()* function as we do the others.

Please help!!!

Comment: Emm user-defined?.. C++ program should have main function when linker links it to the binary code which starts executing the program calling this function. It was not the only way long time ago, not sure how it works nowadays.

Comment: How is this a computer *science* question?

Comment: @Raphael, then tell me to which subject does this question belongs?

Comment: Depends. Where have you found this (very rough) classification? To me, this reads like a programming question.

Comment: Ohhh! I beg your pardon. For giving the tag as *functional-programming*

Comment: One can think of it as an `interface` function that all programs must `implement` for them to do any form of IO (in the compiled rather than interpreted setting); otherwise, it needn't be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library functions are functions that somebody else coded, and are available for use.

User-defined functions are functions that the user defines. This is the case of the C/C++ `main()`.

You can think of `main()` as a placeholder or [hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking). The user supplies it, but the standard library knows to [call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469955/in-c-how-is-the-main-method-initially-called) after initializing itself.